# is it possible to specify package based wildcard in log4j 1.x?

Tags: java, log4j

I tried below package appender in log4jproperties file, But it didn't work.
Please help me to solve this problem.

```
log4j.logger.com.ewp.*.service=ERROR,SERVICELOG

#SERVICELOG appender
log4j.appender.SERVICELOG=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.SERVICELOG.File=C:/Log/service_log.log
log4j.appender.SERVICELOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

There's only a concept of *prefixes* or  *inheritance* in log4j (1.x), so you won't be able to do that.

Refer to https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

You will need to put any *.service leaf package into your configuration file.

Alternatively, you can just use different logger names, maybe some that inverse the naming scheme, or maybe something more symbolic (I mean, if you anyway need dedicated logging this might be valid). Or use a secondary logger if the coding overhead is acceptable.

Think of:

```
Logger log = Logger.getLogger("any.string.prefix.here." + "some.suffix");
```

Edit: if you are able to modify the classpath and put log4j-extras to it, you might get some help with the Filters from there: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/filter/package-summary.html

However AFAICS, ExpressionFilter filters on Message and LoggerMatchFilter filters on *exact* logger names - so these might not be solutions either.